# bash: iptables: command not found

Tags: iptables, path

How do I fix the `iptables: command not found` problem that happened to Debian 7.6?

```
batman@gotham:~$ uname -a
Linux gotham 3.14-0.bpo.2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.14.13-2~bpo70+1 (2014-07-31) x86_64 GNU/Linux
batman@gotham:~$ iptables -L
bash: iptables: command not found
batman@gotham:~$ sudo apt-get install iptables
[sudo] password for batman: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
iptables is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
batman@gotham:~$
```

I googled extensively and most of the answers were for CentOS and Fedora that dated back to 2005 and 2009.

Comment: What's the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: iptables should be in your `PATH` so it is the `sudo` you are missing.

Comment: What happenned to me is that `iptables` is not installed by default. And `sudo apt install iptables` works. OP has `iptables` installed obviously.

Answer (score 21):

The `iptables` command can pretty much only be usefully run as root, not as another user. So it is not in the default command search path for users other than root.

To run `iptables`, run it as root, with either of these commands:

```
su 'iptables --some-option …'
sudo iptables --some-option …
```

The executable is located in `/sbin`, which is in the default command search path for root.

Answer (score 9):

It's because `iptables` is not listed in your `PATH` variable. I think it should work with the `sudo` command. Try:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

If that too doesn't work then you should checkout where the `iptables` binary is and then add it to the `PATH` variable.

In most cases it should be in `/sbin/`. Still, just verify in Debian7. If it is in `/sbin/` then you can open `.bashrc` file and provide this at the end:

```
PATH=/sbin/:$PATH
```

Comment: `you should checkout where the iptables binary is` What command should I type to locate the iptables binary?

Comment: `then you can open .bashrc file and` Where is the location of `.bashrc` file?

Comment: did you check with sudo? Try `dpkg -L iptables` to list out the files.

Comment: What about .bashrc file? Where's it located?

Comment: Well these are the basics. Ok it is in your home directory. Trying opening from your terminal. `vim ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I didn't know that .bashrc file is a hidden file. Anyway I added the `PATH=/sbin/:$PATH` to it.

Comment: and what if it isn't in any of the `/bin/` or `/sbin` dirs?

Comment: @Huey I hope you're joking

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer to your question.
But there are those who are facing the same problem and have not installed `iptable`

**you may try installing the iptables package as shown below as per your choice of distribution.**

| Distribution | Command |
| --- | --- |
| Debian | `apt-get install iptables` |
| Ubuntu | `apt-get install iptables` |
| Alpine | `apk add iptables` |
| Arch Linux | `pacman -S iptables` |
| Kali Linux | `apt-get install iptables` |
| CentOS | `yum install iptables` |
| Fedora | `dnf install iptables` |
| Raspbian | `apt-get install iptables` |

Comment: The answer is not really following the scenario explained in the question

Comment: This page comes up in Google for other scenarios as well. So it is not bad that this answer is included among the answers, it may be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -L iptables` will show where the files are installed from the package `iptables`.

```
dpkg -L iptables | grep iptables$
```

You can check the location of `iptables` binary file. For me on Ubuntu it is in `/sbin/iptables`.

So run with `/sbin/iptables -L`  and check.

Answer (score 0):

In some distributions, `iptables` is not installed, and it's also considered old.

In these distributions, you probably have the `nft` command instead. If yes, you may want to document yourself about `nftables` instead:

https://wiki.debian.org/nftables

This may be a useful tutorial:

https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Moving_from_iptables_to_nftables